# Excel (online)+PowerBI Refresh

Tags: excel, powerbi

I have a PowerBI Online dataset, which was created in PowerBI desktop and then published online. So far so good.

I connect to the dataset from Excel via [PowerBI pusblish](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/analyze-in-excel-from-power-bi-publisher-july-update/), which work as expected. I'm able to refresh the data in the offline version of Excel, but if I attempt to refresh it in Excel online, I get a generic error.

Is it even possible to refresh Excel online which is connected to PowerBI dataset? If not, any possible workaround?

Thanks for any tip

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is an exact answer, but I've got a set up here where the O365 online excel document lives in a sharepoint environment. I was able to add the sharepoint site as a source in PowerBI - so whenever the online excel gets updated (because it resides on the sharepoint server), it's able to be fed into Sharepoint.

Comment: Could you please detail on the solution? I am facing this error with excel online (power BI isn't in the picture). Is there some config needed?